# How to configure Home Assistant to get working SmartIR integration with Tasmota IR over MQTT?

Tags: home-assistant, tasmota

Could someone help me to configure [SmartIR, available on github](https://github.com/smartHomeHub/SmartIR) to use with Tasmota over MQTT?

I have installed the addon with HACS and have generic IR flashed with TasmotaIR (when aiming with remote control to the IR box I can see it's receiving commands on the console).

I'm stuck trying to get working with Gree air conditioner and Samsung TV

This is my configuration.yaml

```yaml
smartir:

media_player:
  - platform: smartir
    name: Bedroom TV
    unique_id: bedroom_tv
    device_code: 1060
    controller_data: cmnd/tasmota_79A072/IRsend
    #power_sensor: binary_sensor.tv_power

climate:
  - platform: smartir
    name: Bedroom AC
    unique_id: bedroom_ac
    device_code: 1180
    controller_data: cmnd/tasmota_79A072/IRsend
    temperature_sensor: sensor.temp_hum_cuarto_temperature
    humidity_sensor: sensor.temp_hum_cuarto_humidity
```

When pushing any buttons on generated cards nothing happens (on the Tasmota console, nothing is showing).

Comment: Load IRdump to the Arduino device and confirm that you receive codes.

Comment: @MatsK I confirmed already receive codes on Tasmota console

Comment: @gsubiran could you post the json to climate code please

Comment: @thieggs Look at my answer again, I have added a climate example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok there are two key properties here to get smartir working over MQTT (with tasmota)

- device_code
- controller_data

**device_code**

I thought that just looking for codes in the github repo [here](https://github.com/smartHomeHub/SmartIR/tree/master/codes) and then setting the value for my device will make it work, but it didn't.

You will need first to upload the [code].json file to your home assistant installation at `config/custom_components/smartir/codes/climate` for air conditioner or `config/custom_components/smartir/codes/media_player` for tv.

That's sounds easy but the most complicated part is that major .json files available on the git repo are for broadlink hardware and don't work for tasmotized devices that communicates through MQTT so you have two options.

1. Google a lot to try to find someone sharing .json file for the same device as yours.
2. Get codes yourself using the original remote control.

To get codes yourself you need to access to your tasmotized device through it web interface and go to "Console". Then get your remote control and pointing to your IR device push a button.
You will see on console information regarding this button you pressed.

[image]

This information you will use to construct your own .json file like this (Samsung TV)

```json
//SAMSUNG TV
{
    "manufacturer": "Samsung",
    "supportedModels": [
      "UE55F8000",
      "UExxF8000"
    ],
    "supportedController": "MQTT",
    "commandsEncoding": "Raw",
    "commands": {
        "off": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E019E6\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x070702FD\",\"Repeat\":0}",
        "on": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E09966\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x070702FD\",\"Repeat\":0}",
        "previousChannel": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E008F7\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x070710EF\",\"Repeat\":0}",
        "nextChannel": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E048B7\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x070712ED\",\"Repeat\":0}",
        "volumeDown": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E0D02F\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x07070BF4\",\"Repeat\":0}",
        "volumeUp": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E0E01F\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x070707F8\",\"Repeat\":0}",
        "mute": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E0F00F\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x07070FF0\",\"Repeat\":0}",
        "sources": {
            "DTV": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E0C23D\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x070743BC\",\"Repeat\":0}",
            "Antenna": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E0D827\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x07071BE4\",\"Repeat\":0}",
            "HDMI": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E0D12E\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x07078B74\",\"Repeat\":0}",
            "HDMI 1": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E09768\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x0707E916\",\"Repeat\":0}",
            "HDMI 2": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E07D82\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x0707BE41\",\"Repeat\":0}",
            "HDMI 3": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E043BC\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x0707C23D\",\"Repeat\":0}",
            "HDMI 4": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E0A35C\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x0707C53A\",\"Repeat\":0}",
            "3D": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E08679\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x0707619E\",\"Repeat\":0}",
            "Channel 0": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E08877\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x070711EE\",\"Repeat\":0}",
            "Channel 1": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E020DF\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x070704FB\",\"Repeat\":0}",
            "Channel 2": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E0A05F\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x070705FA\",\"Repeat\":0}",
            "Channel 3": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E0609F\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x070706F9\",\"Repeat\":0}",
            "Channel 4": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E010EF\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x070708F7\",\"Repeat\":0}",
            "Channel 5": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E0906F\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x070709F6\",\"Repeat\":0}",
            "Channel 6": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E050AF\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x07070AF5\",\"Repeat\":0}",
            "Channel 7": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E030CF\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x07070CF3\",\"Repeat\":0}",
            "Channel 8": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E0B04F\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x07070DF2\",\"Repeat\":0}",
            "Channel 9": "{\"Protocol\":\"SAMSUNG\",\"Bits\":32,\"Data\":\"0xE0E0708F\",\"DataLSB\":\"0x07070EF1\",\"Repeat\":0}"
        }
    }
}
```

Here another example but for climate

```json
//GREE 

{
  "manufacturer":"Gree",
  "supportedModels":[
    "GREE"
  ],
  "supportedController":"MQTT",
  "commandsEncoding":"Raw",
  "minTemperature":16.0,
  "maxTemperature":30.0,
  "precision":1.0,
  "operationModes":[
    "heat_cool",
    "fan_only",
    "dry",
    "cool",
    "heat"
  ],
  "fanModes":[
    "low",
    "mid",
    "high",
    "auto"
  ],
  "commands":{
    "off":"{\"Vendor\":\"GREE\", \"Power\":\"Off\"}",
    "heat_cool":{
      "low":{
          //The following row must be replicated incrementing value 16 at property name end and also at Temp propertie inside. This will make your conditioner set those temps. Removed for code brevity
        "16":"{\"Vendor\":\"GREE\",\"Model\":1,\"Mode\":\"Auto\",\"Power\":\"On\",\"Celsius\":\"On\",\"Temp\":16,\"FanSpeed\":\"Min\",\"SwingV\":\"Highest\",\"SwingH\":\"Off\",\"Quiet\":\"Off\",\"Turbo\":\"Off\",\"Econo\":\"Off\",\"Light\":\"On\",\"Filter\":\"Off\",\"Clean\":\"Off\",\"Beep\":\"Off\",\"Sleep\":-1}",        
      },
      "mid":{
        "16":"{\"Vendor\":\"GREE\",\"Model\":1,\"Mode\":\"Auto\",\"Power\":\"On\",\"Celsius\":\"On\",\"Temp\":16,\"FanSpeed\":\"Medium\",\"SwingV\":\"Highest\",\"SwingH\":\"Off\",\"Quiet\":\"Off\",\"Turbo\":\"Off\",\"Econo\":\"Off\",\"Light\":\"On\",\"Filter\":\"Off\",\"Clean\":\"Off\",\"Beep\":\"Off\",\"Sleep\":-1}",        
      },
      "high":{
        "16":"{\"Vendor\":\"GREE\",\"Model\":1,\"Mode\":\"Auto\",\"Power\":\"On\",\"Celsius\":\"On\",\"Temp\":16,\"FanSpeed\":\"Max\",\"SwingV\":\"Highest\",\"SwingH\":\"Off\",\"Quiet\":\"Off\",\"Turbo\":\"Off\",\"Econo\":\"Off\",\"Light\":\"On\",\"Filter\":\"Off\",\"Clean\":\"Off\",\"Beep\":\"Off\",\"Sleep\":-1}",        
      },
      "auto":{
        "16":"{\"Vendor\":\"GREE\",\"Model\":1,\"Mode\":\"Auto\",\"Power\":\"On\",\"Celsius\":\"On\",\"Temp\":16,\"FanSpeed\":\"Auto\",\"SwingV\":\"Highest\",\"SwingH\":\"Off\",\"Quiet\":\"Off\",\"Turbo\":\"Off\",\"Econo\":\"Off\",\"Light\":\"On\",\"Filter\":\"Off\",\"Clean\":\"Off\",\"Beep\":\"Off\",\"Sleep\":-1}",        
      }
    },
    "fan_only":{
      "low":{
        "16":"{\"Vendor\":\"GREE\",\"Model\":1,\"Mode\":\"fan_only\",\"Power\":\"On\",\"Celsius\":\"On\",\"Temp\":16,\"FanSpeed\":\"Min\",\"SwingV\":\"Highest\",\"SwingH\":\"Off\",\"Quiet\":\"Off\",\"Turbo\":\"Off\",\"Econo\":\"Off\",\"Light\":\"On\",\"Filter\":\"Off\",\"Clean\":\"Off\",\"Beep\":\"Off\",\"Sleep\":-1}",
        },
      "mid":{
        "16":"{\"Vendor\":\"GREE\",\"Model\":1,\"Mode\":\"fan_only\",\"Power\":\"On\",\"Celsius\":\"On\",\"Temp\":16,\"FanSpeed\":\"Medium\",\"SwingV\":\"Highest\",\"SwingH\":\"Off\",\"Quiet\":\"Off\",\"Turbo\":\"Off\",\"Econo\":\"Off\",\"Light\":\"On\",\"Filter\":\"Off\",\"Clean\":\"Off\",\"Beep\":\"Off\",\"Sleep\":-1}",
        },
      "high":{
        "16":"{\"Vendor\":\"GREE\",\"Model\":1,\"Mode\":\"fan_only\",\"Power\":\"On\",\"Celsius\":\"On\",\"Temp\":16,\"FanSpeed\":\"Max\",\"SwingV\":\"Highest\",\"SwingH\":\"Off\",\"Quiet\":\"Off\",\"Turbo\":\"Off\",\"Econo\":\"Off\",\"Light\":\"On\",\"Filter\":\"Off\",\"Clean\":\"Off\",\"Beep\":\"Off\",\"Sleep\":-1}",
        },
      "auto":{
        "16":"{\"Vendor\":\"GREE\",\"Model\":1,\"Mode\":\"fan_only\",\"Power\":\"On\",\"Celsius\":\"On\",\"Temp\":16,\"FanSpeed\":\"Auto\",\"SwingV\":\"Highest\",\"SwingH\":\"Off\",\"Quiet\":\"Off\",\"Turbo\":\"Off\",\"Econo\":\"Off\",\"Light\":\"On\",\"Filter\":\"Off\",\"Clean\":\"Off\",\"Beep\":\"Off\",\"Sleep\":-1}",
        }
    },
    "dry":{
      "low":{
        "16":"{\"Vendor\":\"GREE\",\"Model\":1,\"Mode\":\"Dry\",\"Power\":\"On\",\"Celsius\":\"On\",\"Temp\":16,\"FanSpeed\":\"Min\",\"SwingV\":\"Highest\",\"SwingH\":\"Off\",\"Quiet\":\"Off\",\"Turbo\":\"Off\",\"Econo\":\"Off\",\"Light\":\"On\",\"Filter\":\"Off\",\"Clean\":\"Off\",\"Beep\":\"Off\",\"Sleep\":-1}",
        },
      "mid":{
        "16":"{\"Vendor\":\"GREE\",\"Model\":1,\"Mode\":\"Dry\",\"Power\":\"On\",\"Celsius\":\"On\",\"Temp\":16,\"FanSpeed\":\"Medium\",\"SwingV\":\"Highest\",\"SwingH\":\"Off\",\"Quiet\":\"Off\",\"Turbo\":\"Off\",\"Econo\":\"Off\",\"Light\":\"On\",\"Filter\":\"Off\",\"Clean\":\"Off\",\"Beep\":\"Off\",\"Sleep\":-1}",
        },
      "high":{
        "16":"{\"Vendor\":\"GREE\",\"Model\":1,\"Mode\":\"Dry\",\"Power\":\"On\",\"Celsius\":\"On\",\"Temp\":16,\"FanSpeed\":\"Max\",\"SwingV\":\"Highest\",\"SwingH\":\"Off\",\"Quiet\":\"Off\",\"Turbo\":\"Off\",\"Econo\":\"Off\",\"Light\":\"On\",\"Filter\":\"Off\",\"Clean\":\"Off\",\"Beep\":\"Off\",\"Sleep\":-1}",
        },
      "auto":{
        "16":"{\"Vendor\":\"GREE\",\"Model\":1,\"Mode\":\"Dry\",\"Power\":\"On\",\"Celsius\":\"On\",\"Temp\":16,\"FanSpeed\":\"Dry\",\"SwingV\":\"Highest\",\"SwingH\":\"Off\",\"Quiet\":\"Off\",\"Turbo\":\"Off\",\"Econo\":\"Off\",\"Light\":\"On\",\"Filter\":\"Off\",\"Clean\":\"Off\",\"Beep\":\"Off\",\"Sleep\":-1}",
        }
    },
    "cool":{
      "low":{
        "16":"{\"Vendor\":\"GREE\",\"Model\":1,\"Mode\":\"Cool\",\"Power\":\"On\",\"Celsius\":\"On\",\"Temp\":16,\"FanSpeed\":\"Min\",\"SwingV\":\"Highest\",\"SwingH\":\"Off\",\"Quiet\":\"Off\",\"Turbo\":\"Off\",\"Econo\":\"Off\",\"Light\":\"On\",\"Filter\":\"Off\",\"Clean\":\"Off\",\"Beep\":\"Off\",\"Sleep\":-1}",
        },
      "mid":{
        "16":"{\"Vendor\":\"GREE\",\"Model\":1,\"Mode\":\"Cool\",\"Power\":\"On\",\"Celsius\":\"On\",\"Temp\":16,\"FanSpeed\":\"Medium\",\"SwingV\":\"Highest\",\"SwingH\":\"Off\",\"Quiet\":\"Off\",\"Turbo\":\"Off\",\"Econo\":\"Off\",\"Light\":\"On\",\"Filter\":\"Off\",\"Clean\":\"Off\",\"Beep\":\"Off\",\"Sleep\":-1}",
        },
      "high":{
        "16":"{\"Vendor\":\"GREE\",\"Model\":1,\"Mode\":\"Cool\",\"Power\":\"On\",\"Celsius\":\"On\",\"Temp\":16,\"FanSpeed\":\"Max\",\"SwingV\":\"Highest\",\"SwingH\":\"Off\",\"Quiet\":\"Off\",\"Turbo\":\"Off\",\"Econo\":\"Off\",\"Light\":\"On\",\"Filter\":\"Off\",\"Clean\":\"Off\",\"Beep\":\"Off\",\"Sleep\":-1}",
        },
      "auto":{
        "16":"{\"Vendor\":\"GREE\",\"Model\":1,\"Mode\":\"Cool\",\"Power\":\"On\",\"Celsius\":\"On\",\"Temp\":16,\"FanSpeed\":\"Cool\",\"SwingV\":\"Highest\",\"SwingH\":\"Off\",\"Quiet\":\"Off\",\"Turbo\":\"Off\",\"Econo\":\"Off\",\"Light\":\"On\",\"Filter\":\"Off\",\"Clean\":\"Off\",\"Beep\":\"Off\",\"Sleep\":-1}",
        }
    },
    "heat":{
      "low":{
        "16":"{\"Vendor\":\"GREE\",\"Model\":1,\"Mode\":\"Heat\",\"Power\":\"On\",\"Celsius\":\"On\",\"Temp\":16,\"FanSpeed\":\"Min\",\"SwingV\":\"Highest\",\"SwingH\":\"Off\",\"Quiet\":\"Off\",\"Turbo\":\"Off\",\"Econo\":\"Off\",\"Light\":\"On\",\"Filter\":\"Off\",\"Clean\":\"Off\",\"Beep\":\"Off\",\"Sleep\":-1}",
         },
      "mid":{
        "16":"{\"Vendor\":\"GREE\",\"Model\":1,\"Mode\":\"Heat\",\"Power\":\"On\",\"Celsius\":\"On\",\"Temp\":16,\"FanSpeed\":\"Medium\",\"SwingV\":\"Highest\",\"SwingH\":\"Off\",\"Quiet\":\"Off\",\"Turbo\":\"Off\",\"Econo\":\"Off\",\"Light\":\"On\",\"Filter\":\"Off\",\"Clean\":\"Off\",\"Beep\":\"Off\",\"Sleep\":-1}",
        },
      "high":{
        "16":"{\"Vendor\":\"GREE\",\"Model\":1,\"Mode\":\"Heat\",\"Power\":\"On\",\"Celsius\":\"On\",\"Temp\":16,\"FanSpeed\":\"Max\",\"SwingV\":\"Highest\",\"SwingH\":\"Off\",\"Quiet\":\"Off\",\"Turbo\":\"Off\",\"Econo\":\"Off\",\"Light\":\"On\",\"Filter\":\"Off\",\"Clean\":\"Off\",\"Beep\":\"Off\",\"Sleep\":-1}",
        },
      "auto":{
        "16":"{\"Vendor\":\"GREE\",\"Model\":1,\"Mode\":\"Heat\",\"Power\":\"On\",\"Celsius\":\"On\",\"Temp\":16,\"FanSpeed\":\"Heat\",\"SwingV\":\"Highest\",\"SwingH\":\"Off\",\"Quiet\":\"Off\",\"Turbo\":\"Off\",\"Econo\":\"Off\",\"Light\":\"On\",\"Filter\":\"Off\",\"Clean\":\"Off\",\"Beep\":\"Off\",\"Sleep\":-1}",
        }
    }
  }
}
```

In any case you finally will have your xxxx.json file uploaded on any of those folders and device_code property configured with same number.

**controller_data**

Here you just need to specify the MQTT topic between some other parameters.
MQTT topic is present on your tasmotized device configuration

[image]

`cmnd/<your_mqtt_topic_here>/IRhvac` for air conditioner

`cmnd/<your_mqtt_topic_here>/IRsend` for tv

**Example of configuration.yaml configuration**

```yaml
smartir:
  check_updates: false

media_player:
  - platform: smartir
    name: Bedroom TV
    unique_id: bedroom_tv
    device_code: 1070
    controller_data: cmnd/tasmota_smart_ir_bedroom/IRsend
    #power_sensor: media_player.chromecast_cuarto

climate:
  - platform: smartir
    name: Bedroom AC
    unique_id: bedroom_ac
    device_code: 1180
    controller_data: cmnd/tasmota_smart_ir_bedroom/IRhvac
    temperature_sensor: sensor.temp_hum_cuarto_temperature
    humidity_sensor: sensor.temp_hum_cuarto_humidity
```

Feel free to let me know if something isn't clear!

Comment: thanks so much for your explanation. Infact I found no json file about mqtt irsend.
I used your climate GREE json file for experiment but it's so difficult to set for me.
May be you have a mqtt json file related to a daikin climate or something similar? or you can help me to learn about creating mqtt json of my climate. Thanks so much
Regards from Italy

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the problem is device code 1060 only supports Broadlink and does not support MQTT. Same for device code 1180. Unfortunately, I have found no complete example of using SmartIR with MQTT.

Comment: I finally got it working creating files for each code and setting specific values on each button. Found some examples googling a lot. You trying to do something similar? I could post what I got done.

Comment: @gsubiran If you have figured out the answer for your own question, please post it. It could help others and you will be able to accept it as well.

Comment: @gsubiran I am trying to use tasmota-ir with SmartIR as you are. I am in the process of trying to create a custom json file and so would be very interested in whatever you came up with.

Comment: @R.Keck sure! I thought this post was dead and I found a solution long after so I forgotten put my findings. I'm now writing a post with that information.